# AgGrid Cell Renderer init() function is called twice on onCellValueChanged(), should only be called once

Tags: angular, ag-grid, angular8, ag-grid-angular

I am using `AgGrid` version `18.1.0` and `Angular 8`.

I am trying to do some basic validation on a `Cell Renderer`, but the fact that the `init()` function is being called twice every time `onCellValueChanged()` is called is breaking my validations logic.

FUN FACT: `init()` is only called once if the value you enter into the cell being edited is the same value (EXAMPLE: 123 ---> 123), but twice if the value is different than the current value (EXAMPLE: 123 ---> 321).

How do I resolve this so the `init()` function is only called once?

**My Grid Options...**

```
this.agGridOptions = {
  onGridReady: (grid) => this.onGridReady(grid),
  onCellValueChanged: (grid) => this.updateRowItem(grid),
  enableSorting: false,
  enableFilter: false,
  enableColResize: true,
  unSortIcon: true,
  components : {
    'parameterValueValidator'             : ParameterValueValidator
  }
};
```

**My `onCellValueChanged()` function...**

```
private onGridReady(grid) {
    this.grid = grid;
    this.gridColumnApi = grid.columnApi;
    this.grid.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
}
```

**My grid definition for the component...**

```
{
    headerName: 'Value',
    field: 'paramaterValue',
    width: 500,
    editable: true,
    cellRenderer: 'parameterValueValidator'
  },
```

**Here is my Cell Renderer Component...**

```
import * as moment from 'moment';

export class ParameterValueValidator {
  public eGui: any;
  public getGui() {
    return this.eGui;
  }

  public init(params) {
    this.eGui = document.createElement('div');
    const dataType = (params.data.parameterDataType.toLowerCase());
    const valuesDataType = this.determineDataType(params.data.paramaterValue, dataType);

    if (params.data.paramaterValue === '') {
      this.eGui.innerHTML = '<p><font size="1" color="red">* Required field </font></p>';
    } else if (valuesDataType !== dataType && dataType !== '') {
      this.eGui.innerHTML = '<p><font size="1" color="red" class="data-type-mismatch">* Data type "' + dataType + '" does not match value type "' + valuesDataType + '"</font></p>';
      params.data.paramaterValue = '';
    } else {
      this.eGui.innerHTML = params.data.paramaterValue;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Faced the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Negative. 
Team bought Enterprise and the issue went away.